# Issues re-indexing items in a nested object array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object array with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "uid": "card-vwy733s3rC",
    "body": {
      "text": "Test"
    },
    "type": 0,
    "button": [
      {
        "uid": "button-tFDHsmExnx",
        "title": "Get Started",
        "event": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "action": 5,
            "value": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Educational_technology"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "action": 5,
            "value": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Educational_technology"
          }
        ],
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    ],
    "audio": {
      "uid": "audio-NVBK0U6BXE",
      "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/media.testing.co.uk/default/testing_startup_ideas.mp3"
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to re-index the value at `button -> event -> id` on occasion, provided the topmost uid matches. This means that the two 2's become 1 and 2. However, when I run my method below, it doesn't work, and it returns an identical id's for all the items in the `button -> event` array:

```
  static resetCourseContentButtonEventIndexes(
    courseContent: ICourseContent[],
    selectedCourseContentUid: string
  ): ICourseContent[] {
    for (let i = 0; i < courseContent.length; i++) {
      if (courseContent[i].uid === selectedCourseContentUid) {
        for (let j = 0; j < courseContent[i].button.length; j++) {
          for (let k = 0; k < courseContent[i].button[j].event.length; k++) {
            courseContent[i].button[j].event[k].id = k + 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return courseContent;
  }
```

I'm confused about why this is happening, how can I fix it?

I call it from another method:

```
static cloneCourseContentButtonEventByIndex(
    courseContent: ICourseContent[],
    selectedCourseContentUid: string,
    selectedCourseElementUid: string,
    courseContentButtonEventIndex: number
  ) {
    for (let i = 0; i < courseContent.length; i++) {
      if (courseContent[i].uid === selectedCourseContentUid) {
        for (let j = 0; j < courseContent[i].button.length; j++) {
          if (courseContent[i].button[j].uid === selectedCourseElementUid) {
            courseContent[i].button[j].event.push(
              courseContent[i].button[j].event[courseContentButtonEventIndex]
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return JSON.parse(
      JSON.stringify(
        this.resetCourseContentButtonEventIndexes(courseContent, selectedCourseContentUid)
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yea this is intentional, I am trying to reset it so that they become 1, and 2 respectively by passing it into `resetCourseContentButtonEventIndexes`

Comment: It's working for me as is. Have you narrowed down where the problem may lie?

Comment: No idea, I call it from another method (where the button event is cloned). Could that be the issue? I've included it above.

Comment: yeh, for me it also works, maybe you have a typo in the second argument of the method). Could you console.log the arguments of the method?

Comment: yes, you are pushing a reference to the object here : `courseContent[i].button[j].event.push(courseContent[i].button[j].event[courseContentButtonEventIndex]);`, instead clone the object as you push `courseContent[i].button[j].event.push({...courseContent[i].button[j].event[courseContentButtonEventIndex]});`

Comment: @pilchard thanks for this, how do I go about fixing this. I am not 100% sure I follow, I am cloning the object in the array first and then re-indexing it. How is that causing an issue?

Comment: You are cloning the *returned* array, but passing `courseContent` with the pushed references. Clone the pushed `event` using spread operator as I indicated in the second code line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing references to a single `event` object in your `cloneCourseContentButtonEventByIndex()` method in this line...

```
courseContent[i].button[j].event.push(
              courseContent[i].button[j].event[courseContentButtonEventIndex]
            );
```

To avoid this problem clone the object before pushing it using the spread syntax

```
courseContent[i].button[j].event.push(
              {...courseContent[i].button[j].event[courseContentButtonEventIndex]}
            );
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Pretty odd. But I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: Glad it helped.